# How to use it with promise string label in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I am trying to use a promise as below.

```js
let promiseArray: [string, Promise<unknown>][] = [];
for(const a of array)
{
   const promise = new Promise(() => {this.repository.getRepository<a.entity>.find()});
   promiseArray.push([a.entityName, promise]);
}
```

And the result of the code above is:

```js
result : [
    ['EntityName', [{},{},{}]],
    ['EntityName2', [{},{},{}]],
     ....
]
```

But I don't know how can I apply promiseArray to `promise.all`.

```js
await Promise.all(promiseArray)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
          })
          .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

I tried the above, but it didn't work, and I tried `promiseArray.map((pm)=>pm[1])`, but I couldn't map the value of `pm[0]`.

Comment: How do the promises ever fufill?

Comment: What's `pm` in `promiseArray.map((pa)=>pm[1])`? And, what does that mean, "I couldn't map the value of `pm[0]`"?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen The `pa` and `pm` are probably just a typo, there's nothing else in the code close to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're populating your array wrong. From your code, it looks like you're using TypeORM, and that `.find()` is async (returns a promise). So, you don't need to wrap it in another promise. Try filling the array like this:

```
let promiseArray: [string, Promise<unknown>][] = [];
for(const a of array)
{
   const promise = this.repository.getRepository<a.entity>.find();
   promiseArray.push([a.entityName, promise]);
}
```

Then, all you need to do is a `.map()` to get the second value in the array, which is the promise returned by `.find()`:

```
await Promise.all(promiseArray.map(el => el[1]));
```

If you need to pass the `.entityName` along with the promise's result, then map each element to its `.find()` promise, then add the entity name to the result in a `.then()`. This creates a single promise per element in `array` and can be simply passed to `Promise.all()`:

```
const promiseArray: [Promise<[string, unknown]>][] = array.map(el => this.repository.getRepository<a.entity>.find().then(res => [el.entityName, res]));
const results = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. This code works fine. However, as written in the question above, only the result of `el[1]` is output, how can I combine the values ​​of `el[0]`?

Comment: @Mamochi I've edited my answer with how to do that.

Comment: Oh, I removed the type from promiseArray and it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all` accepts an array of promises, but you have an array of -

```js
Array<[String, Promise]>
```

You will need to construct the array of promises differently -

```js
const promiseArray: Promise<Array<[string, unknown]>> = []

for (const a of array) {
   const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // ...
   })
   .then(result => [a.entityName, result]) // ✅ 
   promiseArray.push(promise)
}
```

Now you can use `Promise.all` -

```js
Promise.all(promisesArray).then(...)
```

Results in -

```js
[
  ['EntityName', <promise result>],
  ['EntityName2', <promise result>],
  ...
]
```

Here's a functioning example -

```js
const randPromise = () =>
  new Promise(r =>
    setTimeout(r, 1000, Math.random() * 100 | 0)
  )
  
const labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
  
const promises = []

for (const label of labels)
  promises.push(randPromise().then(value =>
    [label, value]
  ))
  
Promise.all(promises)
.then(JSON.stringify)
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
// [["a",53],["b",25],["c",22],["d",53]]
```

Instead of using the `for..of` loop, many find it easier to use an array's `map` function -

```js
const randPromise = () =>
  new Promise(r =>
    setTimeout(r, 1000, Math.random() * 100 | 0)
  )
  
const labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
  
Promise.all(labels.map(label =>
  randPromise().then(value => [label, value])
))
.then(JSON.stringify)
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
// [["a",90],["b",20],["c",76],["d",60]]
```

Every `then` expression has an equivalent `async..await` representation. This approach uses fewer nested lambdas and therefore a bit easier to digest -

```js
const randPromise = () =>
  new Promise(r =>
    setTimeout(r, 1000, Math.random() * 100 | 0)
  )
  
const labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
  
Promise.all(labels.map(async label =>
  [label, await randPromise()]
))
.then(JSON.stringify)
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
// [["a",90],["b",20],["c",76],["d",60]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, the problem seems to be the part where promise and find are used together as shown below.